# How to make angularjs log default html5 validation messages when an input field is invalid?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So, I have been working on a project where I use angularjs to validate form input fields. The thing is, I want angularjs log the default html5 validation messages like 'Please Fill out this field' when the input 
fields are empty. It should be something similar to the code below:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myForm");
var y = document.getElementById("email");
var z = document.getElementById("error");

x.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    if (y.checkValidity() === false) {
        e.preventDefault();
        z.innerHTML = y.validationMessage;
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

button {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.error, #error {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Email validation example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" action="?" novalidate="">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" required=""/>
        <span class="error">* <span id="error"></span></span>
        <br/><br/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

A: Notice the `y.validationMessage` in the javascript part of the code. It logs the default html5 input validation messages into the `<span>` element(If you run the snippet, then you might know).

B: My question is: Is there a way where we can make angularjs log the default html5 input validation message like how the `validationMessage` property did?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Like that

```
 <form id="myForm">
       <label for="email">Email:</label>
       <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required=""/> 
       <span ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
       <br/><br/>
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

[Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/nYPzEO8d3SKuFk4KBn1o?p=preview&preview)